# Vue.js. Error at project start Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'e')

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuejs3, webpack-dev-server

I'm new into Vue.js, and I'm running into this error when creating my project. This are the steps I made:

1. Install Vue/cli through cmd

```
npm install @vue/cli
```

2. Create Vue project. I navigated to the desired folder on Visual Studio terminal, since I already have the Back End ready and working. So in the same folder there will be both Back End that works with Node.js and the Vue project to act as Front End. The folder looks like this after executing the command `vue create app-frontend` with Project as Root Folder:

```
- Project
-- api-backend
-- app-frontend
```

3. I manually selected the features, this is what I selected:

- Check the features needed for your project: Babel, Linter/Formatter
- Vue version: 3.x
- Linter/Formatter: ESLint with error prevention only
- Additional lint features: Lint on save
- Prefered placing config for Babel, Eslint, etc.: In dedicated config files

4. Execute commands `cd app-frontend` and `npm run serve`

Once here, accessing localhost:8080 gives me an empty page and this error on the browser console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'e')
    at eval (stripAnsi.js:18:1)
    at ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/utils/stripAnsi.js (chunk-vendors.js:325:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:255:33)
    at fn (app.js:488:21)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/index.js?protocol=ws&hostname=192.168.1.61&port=8080&pathname=%2Fws&logging=none&progress=true&overlay=%7B%22errors%22%3Atrue%2C%22warnings%22%3Afalse%7D&reconnect=10&hot=true&live-reload=true:7:77)
    at ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/index.js?protocol=ws&hostname=192.168.1.61&port=8080&pathname=%2Fws&logging=none&progress=true&overlay=%7B%22errors%22%3Atrue%2C%22warnings%22%3Afalse%7D&reconnect=10&hot=true&live-reload=true (chunk-vendors.js:172:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:255:33)
    at app.js:1374:83
    at __webpack_require__.O (app.js:301:23)
    at app.js:1377:53
```

How do I solve this so I can start my project? Did I do anything wrong? This is the first time I get this error, created other projects on other directories and got no errors, so I don't know what's happening.

Comment: Question: why are you using Vue CLI if you are new to Vue? It is deprecated in favor of Vite. Unless you have specific project requirements, you should not use it.

Comment: Webpack is a nightmare... ;)

Comment: Hi @DarrylNoakes, I am following guides from videos and I guess they might be old. In theory they are updated, but they might be usign it the old way. Will have it in count!

Comment: what do you mean by "created other projects on other directories"? Do you mean that only specific directory in your PC is not working using the method u specified above? Or created other projects such as React using CRA?

Comment: @Remicaster. Yes. The other project I copied was a Vue project made with the same instructions as I mentioned above but was created on another directory and worked.

Comment: Was it created at a different time? Example 1 month ago etc. But based on one of your comments below t I suspect that there might be breaking versions of dependencies in the package.json file, try looking on the working project and the project with issue, look at the versions of the dependencies, see which one is causing the error

Comment: @Remicaster When the error occurred they were created 2 or 3 days before. It might be breaking versions of dependencies, but wouldn't this be avoided when starting a new project? All dependencies added during the initiation of the project should work, right?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you forgot to install:

```bash
cd app-frontend
npm i
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your quick answer! I already tried but I keep with the same error. I managed to make it work by copying all files from another started project into this new one and then running `npm i` to get the modules. This works but I don't know why doing a normal installation is giving me this error

Comment: Which version of VUE cli do you use? Run `vue --version` command

Comment: Using @vue/cli 5.0.8